About the Hölder continuity of the power of a function
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain and assume that $f: \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function in the space $C^{2,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$, $0 < \alpha <1$, such that $f(x) > 0$, for all $x \in \Omega$ and $f(x) = 0$, for all $x \in \partial\Omega$. If $a >1$, is it true that $f^a \in C^{2,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$ ?
I think when a > 1, we can prove that $f ^a \in C^{1,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$. But if $a \leq 2$, I don't know if the above conclusion is true.
For example, we need to show that $$\dfrac{\partial^2 f^a}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(x) = a(a-1)f^{a-2}(x)\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(x) \in C^{0,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega}).$$
To do this, it is enough to show that tehre exists $M > 0$ such that $$\dfrac{\left|f^{a-2}(x)\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(x) - f^{a-2}(y)\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(y)\right|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} \leq M,$$
for all $x,y \in \Omega$, with $x \neq y$. My ideia was the following:
$\left|f^{a-2}(x)\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(x) - f^{a-2}(y)\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(y)\right|  = \left|f^{a-2}(x)\left(\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(x) -\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(y) \right) - \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(y)(f^{a-2}(y) - f^{a-2}(x))\right| \leq |f^{a-2}(x)|   \left|\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(x) -\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(y) \right| + C_2|f^{a-2}(x) - f^{a-2}(y)|$.
Using that $f \in C^{2,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$ we have
$$\left|\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(x) -\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(y) \right| \leq C_3|x-y|^\alpha.$$
The problem arises when I try to analyze the expressions  $f^{a-2}(x) $ and $|f^{a-2}(x) - f^{a-2}(y)|$, because when $x$ and $y$ are very close of $\partial\Omega$, this expressions can become very large. So, I don't know how to solve this problem.

As an FYI, MSE is not a "do my (home)work for me" site. Such posts (e.g. "PSQs") will often be downvoted & closed. If you want meaningful help, please [edit] your post to include relevant context (see here for more), such as your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If need be, this is helpful for formatting math/LaTeX, & Approach0 is nice for searching up past questions.

I edited the question. And now, can you solve the problem?


First a remark: one computes
$$ \frac{\partial (f^a)}{\partial x_j} =  a f^{a-1} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \; ,$$
hence
$$ \frac{\partial^2 (f^a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} =  a(a-1) f^{a-2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} + a f^{a-1} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \, .$$

In dimension $N=1$, consider $\bar{\Omega} = [0,1]$, $f(x) = x$ (which is $C^{\infty}$) and $a = 3/2$. Then $(f^{3/2})'(x) = (3/2) \sqrt{f(x)}$ is not in $C^{0, \alpha}$ for $\alpha > 1/2$, hence $f^{3/2} \not \in C^{1, \alpha}$ for $\alpha > 1/2$. Of course, here $f(x) \neq 0$ for $x=1$, but one can consider instead e.g. $f(x) = (1/\pi)\mathrm{sin}(\pi x)$ and arrive at the same conclusion.


